# Webpack's relative path & absolute path

Tags: webpack-2

In `webpack.config.js` we can write such config file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/script/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
```

Why we should use **absolute path only** in *output* and we can use either relative path or absolute path in *entry*?